# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar líneas largas en vscode?

Tags: vscode

Se me ocurrió abrir un dump de una base de datos en vscode y no me muestra correctamente la líneas largas, las corta mostrando tres puntos (elípsis).

[image: pinshe vscode vete a la merga :'v]

Intenté [una cosas rara que hallé en el SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50862347/how-to-show-full-long-line-in-visual-studio-code-word-wrap-off) poniendo <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
Luego seleccioné la opción `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)`

pero no hallo la entrada:

```
"editor.stopRenderingLineAfter" : -1
```

[image: configuración no hallada en el mardito vscode]

si trato de agregarla me sale un pop up que dice que no se puede editar porque está en modo solo lectura

[image: que clase de eclipse para javascript es este hdsrptm!!]

Comment: Y probaste agregarla?

Comment: jaja sí, me dice `Cannot edit in read-only editor` :C

Comment: entonces deberias buscar como editarla ;).. igual ojo, a veces deprecan cosas.. capaz no existe mas esa clausula...

Comment: Y si.. en ingles dice: "and add the following line:"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54856374/73749

Comment: @gbianchi por cierto ese enlace no sirve ya que el editor ha cambiado y la opción no aparece

Comment: igual tu problema era otro, y yo te buscaba una solucion para el editor... o sea, nada que ver...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utiliza <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> para acomodar tu código ✌

Comment: Entonces bienvenida la respuesta!!!!